# ChartJS does not display when using local Chart.js file

Tags: chart.js

I am having a problem getting Chart.js to display a Chart when using the Chart.min.js file that was installed as a result of using:
npm install chart.js --save (However, if use the CDN supplied file - the chart will display)

To avoid putting paths into my code, I copied the Chart.min.js file from the install directory: ./node_modules/chart_js/dist/Chart.min.js to the directory where my web page is.  Was this the right file to copy?  Anyways, when I reload the App into the Browser, I get a blank display.  There are no error messages at all.

However, if I instead use the CDN supplied file: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Everything works. The Chart fully displays.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chart.js demo</title>
    <script src="Chart.min.js" </script>

</head>
<body>


    <h1>Chart.js Sample</h1>

    <canvas id="countries" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
        <script>
        var pieData = [
            {
                value: 20,
                color:"#878BB6"
            },
            {
                value : 40,
                color : "#4ACAB4"
            },
            {
                value : 10,
                color : "#FF8153"
            },
            {
                value : 30,
                color : "#FFEA88"
            }
        ];
        // Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
        var countries= document.getElementById("countries").getContext("2d");
        new Chart(countries).Pie(pieData);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what am I doing wrong?  Is there an issue with the download?

Appreciate any help with this!

I am running on Mac OS X 10.10.5
I have tried this using both the Safari and FireFox browsers,
and have the same issue of the local Chart.min.js file not working.

Answer (score 3):

You better use the [latest syntax](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html#creating-a-chart) for creating your chart, instead of old one.

also, this is the correct directory where chart.js file resides, when installed through npm :

```
./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js
```

Here is the full code that works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and Safari :

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chart.js demo</title>
    <script src="./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Chart.js Sample</h1>
    <div class="chart-container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px">
        <canvas id="countries"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        var pieData = {
            datasets: [{
                data: [20, 40, 10, 30],
                backgroundColor: ["#878BB6", "#4ACAB4", "#FF8153", "#FFEA88"]
            }]
        };

        // Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
        var countries = document.getElementById("countries").getContext("2d");
        new Chart(countries, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: pieData
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @GRUNT - Hi, your new version worked!  Thanks!  But, can you explain why the CDN version also worked, yet my installed version using the npm command didn't?  When the only diffference between the two, was the specification of the path to Chart.min.js?  Would really like to understand what went on here.  Thanks!

Comment: @GRUNT - I did some more testing.  It seems the width and height specifications are being ignored, and the graph is deciding on it's own size.  Seems there are as lot of undocemented features with ChartJS. From installation, to how it actually works.  There are a lot of other alternatives out there.  I think I will go check them out.  Appreciate you assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem must be the improper closing of the script tag. See below.

**Before:**

```
 <script src="Chart.min.js" </script>
```

**After:**

```
 <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a demo with a local `Chart.min.js` File for your reference!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for helping.  I correct the improper closing, and it still didn't work.  I then pasted your solution into my IDE, and that version also displayed a blank.  However, I recevied this error message:TypeError: new Chart(countries).Pie is not a function. (In 'new Chart(countries).Pie(pieData)', 'new Chart(countries).Pie' is undefined)

Comment: I then loaded up the Chart.js file that was installed via the "npm" command, and it seems to be missing the "Pie" function that the error was referencing. I then went to GitHib, and it seems the version on GitHub does not match the version that was installed when I ran the npm command to install ChartJS, per the directions on the ChartJS website.  Although, I am not sure I am referencing the correct Chart.js on GitHub - I looked at the version on the "Release Branch". Could you try installing via the npm command they mention, and then see if your JSFiddle still works?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1104028 Sorry I don't use `npm`, but I noticed this problem when working with the code, the issue is that it works only for a specific version of `chart.js`, first uninstall the chart.js version you installed `npm uninstall chartjs` please check the internet for proper uninstalling, then you need to install the specific version using `npm install chartjs@0.2.0`, please let me know if this fixes your issue.